# Sequelize: join tables beyond first degree relationship

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following relationships:

- `User` has `Subscription`
- `Subscription` has `Subject`
- `Subject` has `Lesson`

If this was a multi-demensional array, it would look like this:

```
`User` =>
      (`Subscription` => 
                 `Subject` => 
                     (`Lesson`, `Lesson`),
       `Subscription` => 
                 `Subject` =>
                     (`Lesson`, `Lesson`)
       ,  ...)
```

**How do I query the full dataset preserving this structure using Sequelize?** If I had to write it in "sequelize pseudo-code", I would have something like:

```
seq.User.findAll({
include[seq.Subscription.findAll({
include[seq.Subject.findAll({include: [seq.Lesson]}) ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be about what you'd need. You nearly had the idea/flow in your pseudo code. They may be a more efficient way to write this/do this? But this should work

```js
seq.User.findAll({
  where: {},
  include: [{
    model: seq.Subscription,
    include: [{
      model: seq.Subject,
      include: [{
        seq.Lesson
      }]
    }]
  }]
}).then(function(responseFromDB) {
  handle callback
});
```